# Swift - Can't update UITabBar barTintColor

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

in `viewDidLoad` I've tried the following to update the background or "barTintColor" of my UITabBar. I can do this with objective-c by using `[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];`.

What I've tried:

```
    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white;

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white

    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

I'd like to avoid having some weird NSNotificationCenter solution and updating from AppDelegate. Why is this so difficult to achieve in Swift? Would appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** Below methods should work in `Swift 3`.Below code has to go inside your `viewDidLoad` to make it to work.

**Method 1:**

```
    tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.red
    tabBarController?.tabBar.isTranslucent = false
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Method 2:**

**Note:** I am setting `barTintColour` to green to show both method works..

```
    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.green // Its strange why this method didn't worked for you?.Try updating your post with viewDidLoad.Its a better way to understand the issue.
    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.purple
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I can do this with objective-c by using `[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];`

Well, the Swift equivalent of that is `UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black`. (I don't know why you code all refers to `white` if what you want is `black`.)

The fact that you are speaking Swift rather than Objective-C makes *no* difference to this functionality. If this works in an Objective-C version of your app but not in a Swift version, then you are doing something *else* different in the Swift version — something you have not revealed to us.

Comment: The reason why the colors are different is because the `UITabBar` will be different colors at different points in the app. As you can see, I tried `UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor` above in `viewDidLoad` for the correct view controller and it did not work.